# How many different relations exist for a semantic net?

Tags: semantics

I have encountered a few random sources, that explains to a layman what a semantic net is.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONV38l39PsE

this source explains, there are three different relations within a semantic net:

1. is-a-relation
2. has-a-relation
3. is-an-instance-of-relation

   - http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantisches_Netz

The German Wikipedia-article on semantic nets lists more relations:

additionally to the above three relations, four further are enumerated:

4. Synonymy
5. Antonymy
6. Causation
7. Feature

All 7 relations being described by having or not having features of reflexivity, transivity and symmetry.

**Is there a standard set or different sets of relations for semantic nets within linguistics?**

Comment: The question in the title is two iambic tetrameters.

Comment: not intended, is this bad for readability?

Comment: Not at all, it sounds good. :)